# Java Logger only to file, no screen output

Tags: java, logging

I have quite a simple problem but can't find a solution for it.
I have a logger with a file handler added, but it still spams the hell out of my console.
How could I get the logger to solely route all output to a file, with NO console outputs?

Comment: The exclamation mark makes this question seem really exciting.

Comment: which logging framework?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Remove all handlers (using [Logger.getHandlers()](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/logging/Logger.html#getHandlers()) and calling [Logger.removeHandler()](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/logging/Logger.html#removeHandler(java.util.logging.Handler)) for each handler) from the root logger before adding your file handler.

Comment: Logger.getHandlers() returns 0 handler in my case

Comment: When I add FileHandler, the handlers size goes to 1

Answer (score 21):

Old question but to help other developers:

You can also just use `logger.setUseParentHandlers(false)` on your logger.

Comment: Much easier than any other answers.

Comment: This is the most up-to-date, simple and effective answer.

Answer (score 8):

The simplest way to guarantee that nothing will be written to the console is to put:

```
java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.level = NONE
```

in your logging configuration file.

Answer (score 1):

Use log4j with

```
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;

Logger logger = Logger.getLogger("com.whatever");
PropertyConfigurator.configure("file-log4j.properties");
```

and set your display levels in file-log4j.properties:

```
# Root logger option
log4j.rootLogger=INFO, file

# Direct log messages to a log file
log4j.appender.file=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.file.File=index-service.log
log4j.appender.file.MaxFileSize=1MB
log4j.appender.file.MaxBackupIndex=1
log4j.appender.file.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.file.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{ABSOLUTE} %5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n
log4j.appender.file.Append=false
```

Answer (score 0):

I use:

```
Logger logger = Logger.getLogger("MyLog");
    Logger parentLog= logger.getParent();
    if (parentLog!=null&&parentLog.getHandlers().length>0) parentLog.removeHandler(parentLog.getHandlers()[0]);
```